# Limit of the quotient of two analytic functions $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions

Let $f,g$ be two analytic functions on the domain $\Omega$ such that $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ throughout $\Omega$.

I believe $h(z)=f/g$ only has removable singularities(can't really prove it...), for the following reasons. If $g(z_0)=0$, then $f(z_0)=0$, and 
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}h(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{|f(z)|e^{\arg f(z)}}{|f(z)|e^{\arg g(z)}}\\
=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{e^{\arg f(z)}}{e^{\arg g(z)}}=e^{\arg f(z_0)-\arg g(z_0)}.$$ 
So, we define $h(z_0)$ to be this value(EDIT this value is undefined :( ). Also,
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}h'(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{(f'g-g'f)(z)}{g(z)^2}\\
=\lim_{z\to z_0}(\frac{f'}{g}-\frac{g'}{g}\cdot\frac{f}{g})\\
=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f'-hg'}{g}=\ldots?
$$
Now I cannot proceed to prove that $h'(z)$ exist at $z=z_0$.

**How can I make $h$ analytic?**

PS: if $h$ is made analytic, I can prove by integration that $f(z)=e^{\alpha i}g(z)$ for some fixed $\alpha\in \mathbb R$.

Any help with the problem?

Comment: Let $z_{0}$ be a point of $\Omega$. Then $f$ and $g$ have power series expansions in terms of $(z-z_{0})$ on some ball $B_{\epsilon}(z_{0})$. $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ probably implies the lowest powers are the same, and the coefficients have the same magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that $\arg f(z_0) = \arg 0$ and $\arg g(z_0) = \arg 0$ are not defined, and actually $w \mapsto \arg w$ *cannot* be defined as a continuous function in the neighborhood of $w=0$.

But your assumption that $h = f/g$ has only removable singularities correct. It follows directly from [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) because $h$ is *bounded.* Therefore $h$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $\Omega$.

Finally, $|h(z)| \equiv 1$ implies that $h$ is constant because of the maximum modulus (or open mapping) theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$ then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{n}h(z)$ with $h$ analytic and non-zero in  a neighborhood of $z_0$. This implies that $g$ also has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$. Similarly, if $g$  has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$ so does $f$. Hence the zeros of $g$ are cancelled by those of $f$ in the ratio $\frac f g$. This makes $\frac f g$ analytic  function with modulus $1$ hence a constant (by MMP). The constant must have modulus $1$ so it is of the form $e^{i\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is real.

Comment: *“bounded entire function”*? – The domain here is not $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Corrected the proof.

Comment: Shouldn't the first part be the other way around? If  the denominator $g$ has a zero (of order $n$) then the numerator  $f$ has also a zero (of order at least $n$).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why the first sentence is true? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @HoldingArthur If a non-constant analytic function vanishes to some point $z_0$ it has the form I described in the answer and $n$ is called the **order** of the zero. You can refer to Rudin  or Conway for order of zeros.